# MVC5, WebAPI2 and AutoFac not working. All Nuget packages updated

Tags: asp.net-web-api, autofac, asp.net-mvc-5

I've updated all of the nuget packages in my project, as well as the AutoFac MVC5 Integration package (removed MVC4 one) and still no dice.

> Inheritance security rules violated while overriding member: 'Autofac.Integration.WebApi.AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver.BeginScope()'. Security accessibility of the overriding method must match the security accessibility of the method being overriden.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

The package you need can be found by searching for "autofac webapi2" on Nuget.
It is called **Autofac ASP.NET WebApi 2 Integration**.

Comment: I see that they are now released. Thanks, they're working great. However, even if you search for "Autofac WebAPI2", that package does not even show up on the first page. But the package för WebAPI (1) does. Not sure if there's anything you can do about that though.

Comment: if you search nuget for "autofac webapi2" (quotes not needed) ... the package is #2 in the results ... and it fixes the error in the question.

Comment: Sure, but do you usually include version numbers of all components when searching? At least I don't, which caused me to run in to this again today, two years later.

Comment: @MEMark it's not the Autofac library itself being versioned in the name; it's indicating that this is the Autofac library which integrates with WebApi2.  It's own version will increase (now at 3.x I believe) but it will always be the library for WebApi2 integration.

Comment: Autofac.WebApi2 is [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Autofac.WebApi2/)